# How to use onload and onunload in a same javascript program?

Tags: javascript

My code is:-

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function welcome()
        {
            alert("Successfully loaded");
        }
        function bye()
        {
            alert("Unload");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="welcome()" onunload="bye()">

</body>
```

when i execute this only the function for "onload()" is called. Can you tell me how to trigger "onunload()" event also...

Comment: I'm not sure you can `alert` from `onunload`. Try `onbeforeunload`.

Comment: You can read more of [`unload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onunload) and [`beforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onbeforeunload) at MDN

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what browser you test it

The `onunload` event is supported in IE, Firefox, and Safari, but not supported properly in Chrome or Opera.

please try `onbeforeunload`

```
<body onload="welcome()" onbeforeunload="bye()">

</body>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onbeforeunload

Comment: Well, that's an opinion that it's not supported "**properly**", unless there's a specification of what *should* or *should not* (be allowed to) happen in `unload`. Can you provide any reference to that or how Chrome/Opera differs?

Comment: using jquery is not an option?

Comment: @Mahan you can suggest, but I can't see how it could help